# Multiple indexes in Legrand Orange Book template

Tags: indexing, subdividing

I am currently using the [Legrand Orange Book](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) template. Is there any way to create multiple indexes for the template? I tried to use [`multind.sty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multind) but seems it doesn't create anything.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am very happy knowing this template. Thank for asking this question. :-)

Answer (score 5):

(Unfortunately, the template is not a package/class file, so it's necessary to manipulate the `main.tex` file containing the template (download link provided below)

I suggest the usage of `imakeidx` package

Idendify the lines `\usepackage{makeindex}` and replace it by

```
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx} % Required to make an index with automatic generaton of index files
```

Then change `\makeindex` to following two commands (for two indexes, the names are not really important but must differ from each other, for more indexes use more `\makeindex[name=...]` commands accordingly)

```
\makeindex[name=myfirstindex,title={My super sophisticated first index},intoc=true] %%%% % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing
\makeindex[name=mysecondindex,title={My even more sophisticated second index},intoc=true] %%%%
```

Replace any `\index{foo}` with either `\index[myfirstindex]{foo}` or `\index[mysecondindex}{foo}`.

At the end of `main.tex` look for the lines

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex
```

Change to

```
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex[myfirstindex]
\printindex[mysecondindex]
```

[image]

Further questions on configuration depend on the requests -- I refer to `imakeidx` documentation. `--shell-escape` must be enabled for automatic generation of the index file.

### 'Final' document main.tex

It's still necessary to get the `book_2.zip` from here [Legrand Orange Book](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book)

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The Legrand Orange Book
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.4 (12/4/14)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Mathias Legrand (legrand.mathias@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Compiling this template:
% This template uses biber for its bibliography and makeindex for its index.
% When you first open the template, compile it from the command line with the 
% commands below to make sure your LaTeX distribution is configured correctly:
%
% 1) pdflatex main
% 2) makeindex main.idx -s StyleInd.ist
% 3) biber main
% 4) pdflatex main x 2
%
% After this, when you wish to update the bibliography/index use the appropriate
% command above and make sure to compile with pdflatex several times 
% afterwards to propagate your changes to the document.
%
% This template also uses a number of packages which may need to be
% updated to the newest versions for the template to compile. It is strongly
% recommended you update your LaTeX distribution if you have any
% compilation errors.
%
% Important note:
% Chapter heading images should have a 2:1 width:height ratio,
% e.g. 920px width and 460px height.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} % Default font size and left-justified equations

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry} % Page margins

\usepackage{xcolor} % Required for specifying colors by name
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book

% Font Settings
\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
%\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font for headings
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Use the Adobe Times Roman as the default text font together with math symbols from the Sym­bol, Chancery and Com­puter Modern fonts

\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs

% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % BibTeX bibliography file
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

% Index
\usepackage{calc} % For simpler calculation - used for spacing the index letter headings correctly
\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx} % Required to make an index



\makeindex[name=myfirstindex,title={My super sophisticated first index},intoc=true] %%%% % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing
\makeindex[name=mysecondindex,title={My even more sophisticated second index},intoc=true] %%%%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{structure} % Insert the commands.tex file which contains the majority of the structure behind the template

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(6,5){\includegraphics[scale=1]{background}}} % Image background
\centering
\vspace*{9cm}
\par\normalfont\fontsize{35}{35}\sffamily\selectfont
The Search for a Title\par % Book title
\vspace*{1cm}
{\Huge Dr. John Smith}\par % Author name
\endgroup

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COPYRIGHT PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
~\vfill
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Copyright \copyright\ 2013 John Smith\\ % Copyright notice

\noindent \textsc{Published by Publisher}\\ % Publisher

\noindent \textsc{book-website.com}\\ % URL

\noindent Licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 Unported License (the ``License''). You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at \url{http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0}. Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on an \textsc{``as is'' basis, without warranties or conditions of any kind}, either express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.\\ % License information

\noindent \textit{First printing, March 2013} % Printing/edition date

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TABLE OF CONTENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Table of contents heading image

\pagestyle{empty} % No headers

\tableofcontents % Print the table of contents itself

\cleardoublepage % Forces the first chapter to start on an odd page so it's on the right

\pagestyle{fancy} % Print headers again

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 1
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_2.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Text Chapter}

\section{Paragraphs of Text}\index[myfirstindex]{Paragraphs of Text}

\lipsum[1-7] % Dummy text

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Citation}\index[mysecondindex]{Citation}

This statement requires citation \cite{book_key}; this one is more specific \cite[122]{article_key}.

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Lists}\index{Lists}

Lists are useful to present information in a concise and/or ordered way\footnote{Footnote example...}.

\subsection{Numbered List}\index[myfirstindex]{Lists!Numbered List}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Bullet Points}\index[myfirstindex]{Lists!Bullet Points}

\begin{itemize}
\item The first item
\item The second item
\item The third item
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Descriptions and Definitions}\index{Lists!Descriptions and Definitions}

\begin{description}
\item[Name] Description
\item[Word] Definition
\item[Comment] Elaboration
\end{description}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 2
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{In-text Elements}

\section{Theorems}\index{Theorems}

This is an example of theorems.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Theorems!Several Equations}
This is a theorem consisting of several equations.

\begin{theorem}[Name of the theorem]
In $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ all norms are equivalent. It has the properties:
\begin{align}
& \big| ||\mathbf{x}|| - ||\mathbf{y}|| \big|\leq || \mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y}||\\
&  ||\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf{x}_i||\quad\text{where $n$ is a finite integer}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Theorems!Single Line}
This is a theorem consisting of just one line.

\begin{theorem}
A set $\mathcal{D}(G)$ in dense in $L^2(G)$, $|\cdot|_0$. 
\end{theorem}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Definitions}\index{Definitions}

This is an example of a definition. A definition could be mathematical or it could define a concept.

\begin{definition}[Definition name]
Given a vector space $E$, a norm on $E$ is an application, denoted $||\cdot||$, $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^+=[0,+\infty[$ such that:
\begin{align}
& ||\mathbf{x}||=0\ \Rightarrow\ \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}\\
& ||\lambda \mathbf{x}||=|\lambda|\cdot ||\mathbf{x}||\\
& ||\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}||\leq ||\mathbf{x}||+||\mathbf{y}||
\end{align}
\end{definition}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Notations}\index{Notations}

\begin{notation}
Given an open subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the set of functions $\varphi$ are:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Bounded support $G$;
\item Infinitely differentiable;
\end{enumerate}
a vector space is denoted by $\mathcal{D}(G)$. 
\end{notation}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Remarks}\index{Remarks}

This is an example of a remark.

\begin{remark}
The concepts presented here are now in conventional employment in mathematics. Vector spaces are taken over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, however, established properties are easily extended to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.
\end{remark}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Corollaries}\index{Corollaries}

This is an example of a corollary.

\begin{corollary}[Corollary name]
The concepts presented here are now in conventional employment in mathematics. Vector spaces are taken over the field $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, however, established properties are easily extended to $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$.
\end{corollary}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Propositions}\index{Propositions}

This is an example of propositions.

\subsection{Several equations}\index{Propositions!Several Equations}

\begin{proposition}[Proposition name]
It has the properties:
\begin{align}
& \big| ||\mathbf{x}|| - ||\mathbf{y}|| \big|\leq || \mathbf{x}- \mathbf{y}||\\
&  ||\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf{x}_i||\leq \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf{x}_i||\quad\text{where $n$ is a finite integer}
\end{align}
\end{proposition}

\subsection{Single Line}\index{Propositions!Single Line}

\begin{proposition} 
Let $f,g\in L^2(G)$; if $\forall \varphi\in\mathcal{D}(G)$, $(f,\varphi)_0=(g,\varphi)_0$ then $f = g$. 
\end{proposition}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Examples}\index{Examples}

This is an example of examples.

\subsection{Equation and Text}\index{Examples!Equation and Text}

\begin{example}
Let $G=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<3\}$ and denoted by: $x^0=(1,1)$; consider the function:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned} & \mathrm{e}^{|x|} & & \text{si $|x-x^0|\leq 1/2$}\\
& 0 & & \text{si $|x-x^0|> 1/2$}\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
The function $f$ has bounded support, we can take $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x-x^0|\leq 1/2+\epsilon\}$ for all $\epsilon\in\intoo{0}{5/2-\sqrt{2}}$.
\end{example}

\subsection{Paragraph of Text}\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}

\begin{example}[Example name]
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Exercises}\index{Exercises}

This is an example of an exercise.

\begin{exercise}
This is a good place to ask a question to test learning progress or further cement ideas into students' minds.
\end{exercise}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Problems}\index{Problems}

\begin{problem}
What is the average airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?
\end{problem}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Vocabulary}\index{Vocabulary}

Define a word to improve a students' vocabulary.

\begin{vocabulary}[Word]
Definition of word.
\end{vocabulary}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER 3
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapterimage{chapter_head_1.pdf} % Chapter heading image

\chapter{Presenting Information}

\section{Table}\index{Table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}

%------------------------------------------------

\section{Figure}\index{Figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{placeholder}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Bibliography}}
\section*{Books}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book]
\section*{Articles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INDEX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.75cm}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textcolor{ocre}{Index}}
\printindex[myfirstindex]
\printindex[mysecondindex]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works nicely. What I have to do if I would like to add the alphabet on top of every group like the original result from legrand orange book? ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgjZn.jpg)

Comment: @user62301: That's a follow up question -- Please get your Doty and current account merged, too

Answer (score 0):

Complement from [makeindex style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249128/makeindex-style)

1) create MyStyle.ist:

```
delim_0 "\\dotfill\ "
delim_1 "\\dotfill\ "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\vspace*{0.5cm}\\nopagebreak\n\\tikz\\node at (0pt,0pt) [rounded corners=5pt,draw=ocre,fill=ocre!10,line width=1pt,inner sep=5pt]{\\parbox{\\linewidth-2\\fboxsep-2\\fboxrule-2pt}{\\centering\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries\\textcolor{black}{" heading_suffix "}}};\\vspace*{0.2cm}\\nopagebreak\n"
```

Then change \makeindex to following two commands in order to add " options=-s MyStyle.ist " for heading A, B C. etc:

\makeindex[name=myfirstindex,title={My super sophisticated first index},intoc=true,options=-s MyStyle.ist] 
\makeindex[name=mysecondindex,title={My even more sophisticated second index},intoc=true,options=-s MyStyle.ist]