# makeindex style

Tags: winedt, imakeidx

I am using a template from, "The Legrand Orange Book" (name of tex file is main.tex) and the author has a very nice template that looks like:

[image]

However, after using "Make Index" from WinEdt, my index comes out all plain and no color like that above.  He mentioned in his template to run:

```
makeindex main.idx -s StyleInd.ist
```

from the command line.  How can I implement this index template in my document.  In the folder that he has available, he already has the .idx and ind file.  But whenever I run WinEdt's "Make Index", it gets over written to look like:

[image]

How can I make the index in WinEdt to look like the first image above?

Comment: I do not know how to properly set-up WinEdt to achive your goal but a simple solution would be that you open a command window in your working directory and explicitly type `makeindex main.idx -s StyleInd.ist` together with a couple of LateX or PdflateX compilations and it will work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a version of the style file`MyStyle.ist` [here](https://github.com/patito/DiarioDeUmProgramadorDeMerda/blob/master/StyleInd.ist):

```
delim_0 "\\dotfill\ "
delim_1 "\\dotfill\ "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\vspace*{0.5cm}\\nopagebreak\n\\tikz\\node at (0pt,0pt) [rounded corners=5pt,draw=ocre,fill=ocre!10,line width=1pt,inner sep=5pt]{\\parbox{\\linewidth-2\\fboxsep-2\\fboxrule-2pt}{\\centering\\large\\sffamily\\bfseries\\textcolor{black}{" heading_suffix "}}};\\vspace*{0.2cm}\\nopagebreak\n"
```

It uses commands from other packages and the color `ocre`. The following example uses package `imakeidx` for the index generation, because the question is labeled with the tag of the same name.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Setup for MyStyle.ist
\usepackage{calc}                         
\usepackage{xcolor}                       
\definecolor{ocre}{HTML}{F16723}
\usepackage{tikz}                       

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[options=-s MyStyle.ist]

\begin{document}

% Some empty pages for generating the index entries
\setcounter{page}{6}\index{Citation}\null\newpage
\index{Definitions}\null\newpage
\index{Examples!Equation and Text}\index{Corollaries}\null\newpage
\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}\null\newpage

% Index
\begingroup
  % \fbox* settings to fix the code in MyStyle.ist   
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}% 
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
  \printindex
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Variation

If the style file for makeindex is specific for a project, then the style file can be saved with the name of the TeX file, but with extension `mst` (`\jobname.mst`). If makeindex automatically loads such a file without the need to specify the style file via option (see above: `-s MyStyle.ist`).

The environment `filecontents` can be used to put the contents of the style file in the TeX file. The file is written, if it does not exist, but not updated. If package `filecontents` is loaded, the the file is *always* written, even if it exists.

Instead of complicate TeX code, I would use markup commands, which can be defined in the TeX file.

Full example with some changes to the style code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
delim_0 "\\IndexDotfill "
delim_1 "\\IndexDotfill "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "  \\IndexHeading{"
heading_suffix "}\n"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

% Setup for MyStyle.ist
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{HTML}{F16723}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\IndexDotfill}{%
  \nobreak\dotfill\ \nobreak
}
\renewcommand*{\indexspace}{%
  \par
  \vspace{25pt plus 6pt minus 4pt}%
}
\newcommand*{\IndexHeading}[1]{%
  \tikz\node[
    rounded corners=5pt,
    draw=ocre,
    fill=ocre!10,
    line width=1pt,
    inner sep=5pt,
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    minimum width=\linewidth-\pgflinewidth,
  ] {#1};%
  \nopagebreak
  \par
  \vspace{2mm}%
}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

% Some empty pages for generating the index entries
\setcounter{page}{6}\index{Citation}\null\newpage  
\index{Definitions}\null\newpage
\index{Examples!Equation and Text}\index{Corollaries}\null\newpage
\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}\null\newpage

% Index
\printindex

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 8):

Just to let you know how to add additional options on the fly to the command line of `makeindex` in WinEdt.

Open the Execution Modes dialog (Options menu) and select the option 'Enter Extra Switches on Spot' for MakeIndex application

[image]

At compiling time you will be prompted for inserting extra options and type `-s StyleInd.ist`

[image]

If instead you want to add it permanently, type `-s StyleInd.ist` in the field 'Switches'

[image]