# Makeindex button in WinEdt is greyed out

Tags: winedt, makeindex, nomencl

I am about to start using the `nomencl` package.

I have realized that the `makeindex` command is needed.

It would be nice to be able to access that command in WinEdt similarly as can be done with for example `bibtex`. There is also a button in the WinEdt GUI for executing `makeindex`, but it is greyed out. The executable is there, so I cannot understand why it is greyed out/disabled.

1. I saw someone asking the same question in another forum, but it seemed like noone could help that person http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.winedt/7379.
2. I also found a page http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/miktex.html claiming

   > WinEdt and makeindex - For nomenclatures and making an index you'll need to use makeindex. This is installed, but the menu option is greyed out even if you ask for it using the customisation option. The solution is to click the option to get a command line prompt and type in the makeindex line (the line you need will be in the "nomenclatures" or "makeindex" documentation) [2008]

   that this buttun is not supposed to work (my interpretation).
3. I also found a page [makeindex style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249128/makeindex-style/249222#249222) where one of the responses to a question clearly indicates that this button actually could work.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Use the nomencl package from winedt http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/Nomenclature.html

Comment: Thanks. This makes is possible to create the nomenclature, by creating the "Make Nomenclature" option available under the "TeX" menu, but it did not solve my question about the greyed out button for "Make Index".

Comment: You don't have an index. The index source file has normally the ending *.idx and as winedt sees that it isn't present it doesn't activate the button (nomencl use the ending .nlo and not .idx).

Comment: Ah. So it is inherent in the file suffix used by nomencl?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "it"?

Comment: I meant that since `nomencl` has a different file suffix than expected the button `Make Index` (Shift + Ctrl + I) won't work.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you install the `Nomenclature` package from the community of WinEdt users, `WinEdt.org`. It will add a `Make Nomenclature` item  to the `TeX` menu. Here is a direct link for the [package](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/Nomenclature.html).

No button is installed in the toolbar. If you want to have one, open the `Toolbar.ini` file with the `Options interface` and insert `BUTTON="Make_Nomenclature"` between lines 359 and 360 of `Toolbar.ini`:

```
  BUTTON="Make_Glossary"    
  BUTTON="Make_Nomenclature"    
  BUTTON="|"
```

and click on the `Load Current Script` icon.

Comment: Freudian slip? `It ill add`? ;-)

Comment: I  was probably thinking of Nomenklatura :o)

Comment: Hi, as I replied to Ulrike, this makes it possible creating nomenclatures, but it does still not make it possible to use the "Make Index" button which I think is more convenient than going through drop down menus.

Comment: Ah. You are speaking about the button. You could add one, see the winedt documentation, but I personally never use buttons. I would use the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Lars Abrahamsson: I added an explanation to to explain how to get a `Make Nomenclature` button in the tool bar (it's not installed by default).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. But where can I find the `Load Current Script` icon? And where is the `Make Glossary` Button supposed to show up?

Comment: It's the leftmost button in the `Options interface`.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I did not include the \makeindex (or \printindex) commands in my LaTeX file. The \makeindex command will cause the .idx file to be written, and then WinEdt automatically changes the makeindex option in the TeX dropdown menu to not be be greyed out.