# List of words with pagenumbers with glossary : split according to first letter and fancy aspect

Tags: tables, glossaries, indexing

I am trying to build a list of words alphabetically sorted with the corresponding page numbers like this one :

[image]

After each words there are the pages where you can find it in my document. And each words are split depending on their first letters : A, B, C...
I have been looking at "glossaries" package but :
- I don't know how to split words using their first letters.
- I don't know how to format the glossary accordingly !

I am using "book" documentclass.

Thank you all for your help,
Best regards !

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading the question correctly, but isn't an [index](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/indices) what you want?

Comment: I have checked : it looks perfect, thank you! You are right, index looks way better than glossaries. And I have found this thread, it looks like what I want to do!
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249128/makeindex-style