# Little help to format my .ist

Tags: imakeidx

I don't really get the wording of `ist` files to format an `index`.

Based on  [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249128/makeindex-style) to format the `ist`.

When I try to apply bf series to first level item in my index, I get an error as in the MWE below.

```
<inserted text> 
                }
l.19 \end{theindex}
```

Something is breaking, but how can I fix that ?

[image]

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{MyStyle.ist}
delim_0 "\\IndexDotfill "
delim_1 "\\IndexDotfill "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "  \\IndexHeading{"
heading_suffix "}\n"

% https://winnt.developpez.com/tutoriels/latex-index/
%Generates an error when adding these to get the item in bold
%item_0 "\n \\item \\bfseries{" 
%item_x1 "}\\normalfont\n \\subitem "

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Setup for MyStyle.ist
%--------------------------------------
% Formatage de l'index avec Tikz
%--------------------------------------

\newcommand*{\IndexDotfill}{%
  \nobreak\dotfill\ \nobreak
}
\renewcommand*{\indexspace}{%
  \par
  \vspace{25pt plus 6pt minus 4pt}%
}
\newcommand*{\IndexHeading}[1]{%
  \tikz\node[
    rounded corners=5pt,
    draw=orange,
    fill=orange!10,
    line width=1pt,
    inner sep=5pt,
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    minimum width=\linewidth-\pgflinewidth,
  ] {#1};%
  \nopagebreak
  \par
  \vspace{2mm}%
}
%--------------------------------------

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns  = 2, title  =Index, options = -s MyStyle.ist]


\begin{document}

% Some empty pages for generating the index entries
\setcounter{page}{6}\index{Citation}\null\newpage  

\index{Definitions}\null\newpage

\index{Examples!Equation and Text}\index{Corollaries}\null\newpage

\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}\null\newpage


\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: I ran your example it gave no error and [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITYmE.png) what exactly did you input that gave the error you show?

Comment: ah sorry you have it commented out didn't notice that, I'll test...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it's actually when I uncommen `item_0 "\n \\item \\bfseries{" 
item_x1 "}\\normalfont\n \\subitem " that I get an error.
`

Comment: `\bfseries{` looks very odd, `\bfseries` doesn't take an argument, but I'll have a look...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Odd indeed. And if i try `item_0 "\n \\item \\bfseries"  item_x1 "\\normalfont\n \\subitem "` without braces after \befseries, I get another error (worse :)

Comment: you need a space after bfseries otherwise you get `\bfseriesCitation` which doesn't end welll

Comment: the trick here is to just look at the generated `.ind` file rather than letting latex input that and give arbitrary error messages if it's been generated incorrectly, it's much easier to debug that way

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just started playing with Index, thanks for this useful trick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to generate `{\bfseries...}` not `\bfseries{....`

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{MyStyle.ist}
delim_0 "}\\IndexDotfill "
delim_1 "\\IndexDotfill "
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "  \\IndexHeading{"
heading_suffix "}\n"


item_0 "\n \\item {\\bfseries " 
item_x1 "}\n \\subitem "

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Setup for MyStyle.ist
%--------------------------------------
% Formatage de l'index avec Tikz
%--------------------------------------

\newcommand*{\IndexDotfill}{%
  \nobreak\dotfill\ \nobreak
}
\renewcommand*{\indexspace}{%
  \par
  \vspace{25pt plus 6pt minus 4pt}%
}
\newcommand*{\IndexHeading}[1]{%
  \tikz\node[
    rounded corners=5pt,
    draw=orange,
    fill=orange!10,
    line width=1pt,
    inner sep=5pt,
    align=center,
    font=\sffamily\bfseries\large,
    minimum width=\linewidth-\pgflinewidth,
  ] {#1};%
  \nopagebreak
  \par
  \vspace{2mm}%
}
%--------------------------------------

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns  = 2, title  =Index, options = -s MyStyle.ist]


\begin{document}

% Some empty pages for generating the index entries
\setcounter{page}{6}\index{Citation}\null\newpage  

\index{Definitions}\null\newpage

\index{Examples!Equation and Text}\index{Corollaries}\null\newpage

\index{Examples!Paragraph of Text}\null\newpage


\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Silly me ! I was misleaded in the explanations of the link. Merci :)