# How to change sort order of items in index

Tags: sorting, makeindex

The default sort order for items in my index is not what I want. By default, it seems all capitalized italicized words are in the first section of the index, sorted alphabetically;  followed by all uncapitalized italicized words in a second block, sorted alphabetically; followed finally by all unitalicized words sorted alphabetically, ignoring capitalization. I would prefer all items in the index be simply sorted alphabetically. How can this be done?

Here is a sample .tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Test}
Testing\index{apple}, 
one\index{Apricot}, 
two\index{\textit{avocado}}, 
three\index{\textit{Almond}},
four\index{banana}, 
five\index{Broccoli}, 
six\index{\textit{beans}}, 
seven\index{\textit{Barley}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Here is what the output index looks like:

[image: produced index]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the sorting to the `index` command like `\index{avocado@\textit{avocado}}` so that it will be italic in the Index and sorted as `avocado`.

You can define a command to make it easy (use only for text because of `\textit`):

```
\newcommand{\itindex}[1]{\index{#1@\textit{#1}}}
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\newcommand{\itindex}[1]{\index{#1@\textit{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Test}
Testing\index{apple}, 
one\index{Apricot}, 
two\itindex{avocado}, 
three\itindex{Almond},
four\index{banana}, 
five\index{Broccoli}, 
six\itindex{beans}, 
seven\itindex{Barley} 

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't better to modify the`.ist` file and add appropriate  commands?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619164/little-help-to-format-my-ist