# Compiling problems a book template file Legrand Orange Book

Tags: overleaf, templates

If I try to compile this template, for example, directly in Overleaf, then the list of sources, table of contents, and index have the required form, however, due to the large volume planned, it is difficult to compile the file in Overleaf using the free plan.

To compile on your own machine, ***use a combination of MikTex + TeXWorks***. Problems arise already at the initial stage.

1. When compiled in Overleaf, the bibliography looks as it should, but when compiled offline, an extra page appears with an empty section table of contents, and the list of sources is already displayed only on the next page, however, not quite as required. The picture on the left is what is required, on the right is the result of compilation locally, not in Overleaf.

[image]

2. The formatting of the subject index completely fails:
   [image]

***As I understand it, there are often problems with compiling this template, however, I use the latest libraries and version of the program, i.e. the file compiles, but just not quite as it should... The question is how to solve this problem - how to configure the configuration?***

Comment: compare the log-files (and the blg-files and the ilg-files) to find out what is different locally and on overleaf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer

The only difference is that in the first case version 2.16 is used and in the second 2.17 for `makeindex`...

Comment: there must be more differences if no style is applied. In any case: the index is probably wrong because you didn't call makeindex with the correct style option, it should be something like `makeindex main.idx -s indexstyle.ist`. I have no idea why the colors are wrong, the sample in the template looks ok here.

Comment: The `main.tex` contains the compilation method:  1) `pdflatex main` 2) `makeindex main.idx -s StyleInd.ist` 3) `biber main` 4) `pdflatex main` (twice)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer

I change only color....

Comment: @hair-splitter

I get only this index, which is presented at the screenshots in my post

Comment: I want to say, as a result, that on the one hand, this template is very cool, but on the other hand, the features of using styles, and its compilation in TeX Works leaves much to be desired, the solution from this post helped https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249128/makeindex-style. Now everything compiles almost perfectly!